# Android Grid View with Custom base Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout

i have started to learn android development. i am making an app in which i want to show movie thumbnails(image view and text view) combined in grid view layout i have made custom adapter but problem is that i cannot figure it out how to show image view and text view together.when i run app it shows blank white screen. i have tried many solution and also googled a lot but i cannot figure it out how to do this please help me. Here is my code.

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

        mContext = c;
      //
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        NewHolder holder = null;
        ImageView imageView;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );



        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new NewHolder();

            convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,viewGroup,false);


            holder.imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            holder.textView = new TextView(mContext);

            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);



         //   holder.textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //textView.
           // textView.setText("Hello");
            holder.imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        }


        else {
            holder = (NewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            //imageView= (ImageView) convertView. ;
            //textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }


//        convertView.
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
     //   holder.textView.setText("hello");
        return convertView;



    }



    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };

}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
     //   setContentView(gridview);

    }
```

Holder Class

```
public class NewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }
```

Main Xml Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to your issue.
You're using the adapter incorrectly. You're inflating the 'GridView' with the adapter in this line.

```
convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,viewGroup,false);
```

That's no what you want to do. You want to make an other `XML Layout` that represents each movie's title in a `TextView` and image in an `Imageview`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/movieimage"
    android:src="@drawable/moviethumb"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/movie_title"
    android:id="@+id/todo_list_item_bottom_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This tutorial should help you. It's for a list view but all adapters in android pretty much work the same way.
[Adapter Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter)

I noticed a something you can improve upon. Put your `inflator` inside you `convertview == null`. There's no point to creating this object when it's not used.

Answer (score 1):

You should not inflate the main activity layout in your adapter. Instead you should have a layout of the individual row to inflate in your `getView()` method.

What you have to do is, You have to give adapter a list of data you want to set in gridview. Adapter inflates the rows **(the individual item in Grid)** according to the count of data(models) given, then you will have to assign the data to the individual elements of the row.

So, I have corrected the adapter. Hope this will be helpful:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;



    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };

    private String mTexts[]={"a","b","d",....,"your texts"};

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length; // adapter inflates the row according to the count of data given
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return mThumbIds.length;// inflates rows according to data given
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        NewHolder holder = null;
        ImageView imageView;

        if(convertView==null){//if convert view is null then only inflate the row
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout,viewGroup,false);

            holder = new NewHolder();

            //find views in item row
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_id);
            holder.textView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else { //otherwise get holder from tag
            holder = (NewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //set data here
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        holder.textView.setText(mTexts[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    public class NewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

and your **grid_item.xml** should have layout for each item in GridView like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/imageview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own grid item layout.

**layout/grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridItemIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridItemTextTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Change:

```
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new NewHolder();
        convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,viewGroup,false);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridItemIV)
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridItemTextTV)
     }else {
...
```