# Grid with 4 columns and 2 rows

Tags: android, xml, grid

I want create a grid for my future blocks.These blocks will display measurements retrieved from a weather station.

How to create a grid with 4 columns and 2 rows please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `BaseAdapter`
I think this will work any doubt just say :)

Comment: What is it please? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076806/android-grid-view-with-custom-base-adapter

Comment: Maybe you will need this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129337/android-gridview-with-custom-baseadapter-get-clicked-view-at-position

If you have any doubt or you can't understand what is a baseAdaptar just say :)